# How to make my XAMPP server public on the internet?

Tags: server, xampp, ip, port80

I am trying to make my XAMPP server public on the internet. But when i try to access it  using my ip adress it says connection refuzed. I have followed lots of tutorials but most of them are for older versions. I have set the 80,443 ports on and have added them as a firewall exception but it still not working. Can you please give me some sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the same no matter the version of XAMPP you are using. 
It's not clear if you configured port forward on your router (all connections on ports 80 or 443 will be forwarded to the XAMPP "server"). You should do this orderwise the incoming connection will never be redirected properly.

I am not sure if ISPs can block external access to ports 80 or 443, but you can also configure an alternative port, like 8000, to be forwarded to 80 internally, then you access your server using http://[your_public_IP]:8000

There are some sites you can use to check your public IP, like: http://whatismyipaddress.com/.